# Can't create an Account User using SOAP API in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to create a User Account using SOAP, I'm trying to follow some steps, This is the Envelope I'm sending

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:header>
  >
  <fueloauth>xxx</fueloauth>
</soap:header>
<soap:Body><CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <Options>
    <SaveOptions>
      <SaveOption>
        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
        <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
      </SaveOption>
    </SaveOptions>
  </Options> 
  <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
    <Client>
      <ID>1234565</ID>
    </Client>
    <UserID></UserID>
    <Password>GUCCIHATS*2023!</Password>
    <Name>Taoufiq BENALLAH LV</Name>
    <Email>taoufiq.benallah@gmail.com</Email>
    <NotificationEmailAddress>taoufiq.benallah@gmail.com</NotificationEmailAddress>
    <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
    <IsAPIUser>true</IsAPIUser>
    <IsLocked>false</IsLocked>
    <MustChangePassword>true</MustChangePassword>
    <DefaultBusinessUnit>7225725</DefaultBusinessUnit>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <ObjectID>05245651-6447-e511-bb64-ac162dbd280c</ObjectID>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <ObjectID>11245651-6447-e511-bb64-ac162dbd280c</ObjectID>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
    <AssociatedBusinessUnits>
      <BusinessUnit>
        <CustomerKey>0FC6FF9F-C3A5-46D4-A3B2-FEA655EA7CC5</CustomerKey>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </AssociatedBusinessUnits>
  </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

The response is BAD Request

In POSTMAN, this is the request endpoint
*https://mcxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx*

In Postman, I'm sending body as XML

[image]

Any help wwould be much appreciated.

Comment: I’ve edited your post to hide the token and endpoint you shared

Comment: I changed them before Posting, but thanks Sir